# Netty Server is not returning response when HttpObjectAggregator is removed from pipeline

Tags: netty

I'm trying to create simple HTTP Server using netty 4.1.16.Final.

Below is the code for HTTP Server -

```
EventLoopGroup masterGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
EventLoopGroup slaveGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
final ServerBootstrap bootstrap =
                    new ServerBootstrap()
                            .group(masterGroup, slaveGroup)
                            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                                @Override
                                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                                    ch.pipeline().addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec());
                                    ch.pipeline().addLast("aggregator",
                                            new HttpObjectAggregator(512 * 1024));
                                    ch.pipeline().addLast("request",
                                            new HTTPSimpleChannelInboundHandler());
                                }
                            }).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                            .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
            channel = bootstrap.bind(8080).sync();
```

code for HTTP Handler class `HTTPSimpleChannelInboundHandler` is below -

```
public class HTTPSimpleChannelInboundHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {

    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest request) {
        HttpResponseStatus responseStatus = OK;
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, responseStatus, Unpooled.copiedBuffer("My Netty".getBytes()));
        response.headers().add(request.headers());
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
        if (isKeepAlive(request)) {
            response.headers().set(CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.KEEP_ALIVE);
        }
        if (is100ContinueExpected(request)) {
            ctx.write(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, CONTINUE));
        }
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
    }

    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine.
But when I comment the below line in server code, I didn't get the response.

```
ch.pipeline().addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(512 * 1024));
```

Below is the log I got from the server -

```
01:37:14.806 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - Discarded inbound message DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5055
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.177481759.1523295602; Idea-46064427=2276f52b-2928-4410-8f4c-c7561bd33457
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.
01:37:14.806 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - Discarded inbound message EmptyLastHttpContent that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.
```

Any reason why HttpObjectAggregator is mandatory in the ChannelPipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that if you want to act on `FullHttpRequest` you need the `HttpObjectAggregator` in the pipeline which will take care of assembly these.

Without this you will receive `HttpRequest`, `HttpContent`, `LastHttpContent` instances which represent parts of a HTTP message. Each of them needs to be handled, while a `HttpRequest` marks the start of a new HTTP message and `LastHttpContent` the end of it.